# I have to "write a program that adds all numbers from 2 to 10,000 to a list

Tags: python, helper

I have to "write a program that adds all numbers from 2 to 10,000 to a list. Then remove the multiples of 2 (but not 2), multiples of 3 (but not 3), and so on, up to the multiples of 100. Print the remaining values." This is what I have so far down below, and I keep getting an error?

```
list = []
for i in range(2, 101):
    list.append(int(i))
lenList = len(list)
print(lenList)
for i in range(lenList):
    for j in range(2, 101):
        if lenList[i] != j and lenList[i] % j == 0:
            sum =0
for element in list:
    print(element)
```

> if lenList[i] != j and lenList[i] % j == 0: TypeError: 'int' object is
>   not subscriptable

Comment: Yes, I didnt know how to indent correctly on stack overflow but in my program its running. Just getting an Error?

Comment: Click "edit" to edit your question, delete all the code that's currently there, copy/paste the code from your script, make sure it's all selected and press CTRL + K once.

Comment: @jDo he's just not familiar with how to format SO questions that's all. Have a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: This looks like a "please do my homework" question and I am tempted to flag it.

Comment: @MikeVella I know. But helpful link you posted; saves some typing.

Comment: Good one @marienbad maybe I just need some help?

Comment: just so you clean a bit your code: range(2,101) is already a list and you can assign it, no need to append its elements to another list. Also you can do inline filtering of lists by doing something like new_list = [x for x in old_list if condition]. Also the last print can be done more efficently with a join with '\n'.join(your_list)

Comment: about your last edit, you keep using lenList[i] when lenList is an integer

Comment: Just for fun: `print([n for n in range(2, 10001) if all(n%v or n==v for v in range(2, 101))])`

Answer (score 0):

`lenList` is not a list - it's the length of the list as defined in the line:

```
lenList = len(list)
```

You probably meant to write

```
if list[i] != j and list[i] % j == 0:
```

Comment: @JackMeyers you can accept the answer if it's what you need.